# How to eliminate one day older record based on a date field in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I would like to eliminate the records which are created before one day. 
For example

A record which created one a day and the date will be stored in a field called created in postgres sql

I have tried following but its not working

```
SELECT * from customer WHERE to_timestamp(last_login) < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 days'
```

Its showing error like

```
function to_timestamp(date) does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deriving from the error msg that your "timestamp" is actually a `date`:

```
SELECT * from customer WHERE last_login < CURRENT_DATE - 1;
```

Gets all rows with `last_login` before "yesterday" as defined by the current time and time zone setting of your session.